# jquery autocomplete search not working second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

```
$(elem).autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            if (!names.length){
                                names = [NoResultsLabel];
                            }
                            response(names);
                        },
                        response: function (event, ui) {
                            ui.content.push({
                                label: "<button style=\"float:left;\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"optionless\" onclick=\"previousSchools('"+elem.id+"','"+elem2.id+"')\"><<</button> <button style=\"float:right;\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"optionless\" onclick=\"newSchools('"+elem.id+"','"+elem2.id+"')\">>></button>",
                                button: true
                            });
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            if (ui.item.label === NoResultsLabel) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                            for(var i=0;i<data.schools.length;i++){
                                if(ui.item.label == names[i]){
                                    elem2.value = ids[i];
                                    i = data.schools.length;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        close: function( event, ui ) {
                            requests_schools = 0;
                        }
                    });
                    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                        if(item.label == '<button style="float:left;" class="btn btn-default" id="optionless" onclick="previousSchools($(elem))"><<</button> <button style="float:right;" class="btn btn-default" id="optionless" onclick="newSchools($(elem))">>></button>')
                            return $("<li class='button-element'></li>")
                                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                    .html(item.label)
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                        return $("<li></li>")
                                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                .html(item.label)
                                .appendTo(ul);
                    };
                    openSchoolsSuggestions(elem);
```

this is the autocomplete, i have many results having the same name with slight differences so i designed a custom "paginator" by adding the button in the response, the thing is it works for the first page, but next it close the autocomplete window and deletes the input (for the name) value

Next and previous functions for the paginator:

```
  function newSchools(elemx,elem2){
        var elem = $('#'+elemx);
        if(requests_schools < 0)
            requests_schools = 0;
        requests_schools++;
        var value = elem.val();
        elem.autocomplete( "destroy" );
        elem.val(value);
        getSchools(document.getElementById(elemx),document.getElementById(elem2));
    }

    function previousSchools(elemx,elem2) {
        var elem = $(elemx);
        requests_schools--;
        if (requests_schools >= 0) {
            var value = elem.val();
            elem.autocomplete("destroy");
            elem.val(value);
            getSchools(document.getElementById(elemx),document.getElementById(elem2));
        }
    }

    function openSchoolsSuggestions(elem){
        elem = $(elem);
        elem.autocomplete("search");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, i needed to change the selector in newSchools and previousSchools, first line transformed to `var elem = $(document.getElementById(elemx));`